# MVC2 Nerd Dinner Windows authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I am working on MVC2 and have borrowed lot of things from Nerd Dinner project. Problem is Nerd Dinner uses form authentication where as I want to use Windows Authentication and not only that we want user to input credentials again when they try to access site in intranet even though they are logged into into network using there win. credentials. I have tried to implement this by setting Basic Authentication to true on IIS(followed [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/authenticating-users-with-windows-authentication-cs))
So far everything works great - window popups for user when they try to use site on intranet. However I have two problems - 
1)user accessing website(via login pop up) is not forced to same as user logged into windows. example person "a" logged into windows and same person logged into intranet site using credentials of person "b". I have tested and it works. Is it possible for me to enforce that person logged into windows should be same as try to access site on intranet?
2)When this site is accessed on intranet, is it possible to log into db who current user is in windows and who current user is accessing this site.

I hope it is explained properly. 
Note: Should I implemented this in any other better way? if so, how?

Thanks,